# Assign a custom class for each character in string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using a Vue.js for this demo.

PROBLEM: It works fine except that when I remove a character inside the input field, it ignores and repeats the process with last string.

I have an input field with where I type the text, which uses `v-model`.

```
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="text" />
```

Once I type for example: ***"Some text."***, I would like to wrap each character into the `<span class="styleX"></span>` tag, like so:

```
<span class="style1">S</span>
<span class="style2">o</span>
<span class="style3">m</span>
<span class="style4">e</span>
<!-- whitespace stays untouched -->
<span class="style6">t</span>
<span class="style7">e</span>
<span class="style8">x</span>
<span class="style9">t</span>
<span class="style1">.</span>
```

[HERE IS THE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-mestorf-j0mz9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

What's the proper way to resolve this ?

Comment: Have you tried using this.$set or Vue.set?

Comment: @gorevanova I've tried that too, question is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically want to round-robin across your existing css-classes while still being able to remove characters?

```html
// in your template
<div class="output-wrap">
  <h2>Output:</h2>
    <div>
      <span
        v-for="(item, i) in text.split('')"
        :key="item + i"
        :class="`style${i % styles.length}`"
      >
        {{ item }}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
// in your script
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      text: "",
      styles: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    };
  },
};
```

This uses the modulo operator to help loop across your styles. This will also always yield the same results, not random ones.
Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-shannon-8qysz?file=/src/App.vue) as an example.

You should be very, very, very cautious with `v-html` because it might make your website vulnerable to some attacks. There is also an eslint-rule for this:

> This rule reports all uses of v-html directive in order to reduce the
> risk of injecting potentially unsafe / unescaped html into the browser
> leading to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-v-html.html#rule-details